# Chef Attributes Structure

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-attributes

I am just trying to understand if there is a difference on how we define the attribute structure in the cookbook's attribute files.

Following are two examples:

```
// style-A
default['my_cookbook']['name'] = 'something'
default['my_cookbook']['version'] = '0.1.0'

// style-B
node.default.my_cookbook = {
  :name => 'something',
  :version => '0.1.0'
}
```

The reason I am asking this question is, in the previous versions of chef I kind of remember style-A is highly recommended and all the community cookbooks follow this style. I also recall seeing some issues with the style-B when I used to try to override the attributes from role or environment I would come up with a weird behavior that replaces the whole hash structure if I tried to override a single attribute in it.

I am not seeing this error now and I am on the latest 11 version of chef but was just wondering if this is something I should worry about. I am trying to be consistent with all my cookbooks with a single style and I need some advice on how I structure it. Does it matter at this point?

Comment: Chef uses Mash, rather than hash.  Not sure if it auto-converts for you or not.  I'd suggest = Mash.new({you hash}) personally.  But I can't swear it matters.

Comment: It does, the main drawback between A and B was the method access in overrides which was not overriding due to the method returning the value and not setting it. `default['test'] = { :name => 'test1' }` is perfetcly valid and working. Just stay on the symbol or string attribute access to avoid the method fail on overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `default['key']['subkey']` style, `default` is a `Mash` and the `[]=` method of Mash will convert `Hash` or an array of hashes to a Mash.

The `node.default.property =` style will assign a `Hash` without calling the `[]=` method.

Mash inherits from Hash providing additional functionality, as well as overriding the default value of the initializer to `{}` which makes any undefined values a hash, which is then converted to a mash because of the behavior of mash.